# Proof that there are exactly $n$ $n$th roots of a complex number (Tom Apostol ex $9.10.8.b$)

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, solution-verification

Excercise $9.10.8$ in Tom Apostol's Calculus is to prove that there are exactly $n$ distinct $n$th roots of a complex number $z$.

Let $z = re^{i\theta} \ne 0$, $R=r^{\frac{1}{n}}$, $z_1 = Re^{\frac{i \theta}{n}}$, $\epsilon=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$, where $n$ is a positive integer.

We can easily prove that $z$ has the following $n$ $n$th roots: $r_0 = z_1, r_1 = \epsilon z_1, r_2 = \epsilon^2 z_1 ... r_{n-1} = \epsilon^{n-1}z_1$.

However, I'm not sure what the easiest way would be to prove there are no more than those $n$ roots.

My idea was to start with the definition of the exponential function, from which it follows that we know that any $n$th root has to have modulus $R$, so any $n$th root has to be of the form $r_x = Re^{i\phi}$.

When we raise that to the $n$th degree, then we get:

$r_x^n = re^{in \phi} = re^{i\theta}$
$\implies n\phi =\theta + 2k\pi \implies \phi = \frac{\theta + 2k\pi}{n}$

That is exactly the form of the $r_k$ solutions we constructed above, so $r_x$ has to be one of them.

Is that a correct proof? If not, at what point did I derail?

Thanks!

Comment: Alternate approach: You have found $n$ distinct roots to the polynomial $x^n-z$. It can't have more.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks! I suppose $x$ in that polynomial is complex variable, and that is the $n$th root of $z$, while $z$ is the constant I'm looking the $n$th root of? If you are certain my approach is fine, can you please add your comment as full answer, so I can close the question?

Comment: That's exactly how to interpret my comment. However, I haven't looked too closely at your solution, and since your question was about your solution, not directly about how to solve the problem, I left it as a comment.